# PowerBI Field Formatting Section Not Showing for a Matrix Visualization

Tags: matrix, powerbi, formatting

I have a simple PowerBI Matrix visualization and I need to justify columns left or right selectively. However, the Field Formatting section is not available or does not show up for some reason.[image: Missing Field Formatting section]

Comment: It appears that the Field Formatting section under Format is only available for the matrix visualization columns that get added to the Values section under Fields. Why? What about other columns that cannot be moved to Values and require left/right justification?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found it under "Specific Columns", really confusing! Hope this helps.